# variable not defined in forEach() javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach, undefined, typeof

using this simple function to iterate through an array and display the element, index and type, im trying to add an "n" to the word a for words that begin with a vowel. eg. a number, an object.

however the variable "n" that adds the n is coming as undefined in the final console.log

i beleive its a scope error, but being new to javascript im asking for help

```js
const someArr = [
  'max',
  34,
  true,
  {
    name: 'sandra',
    student: true
  },
  ['javascript', 'mongodb', 'react']
];

////////////////

function arrayTypeFinder(array) {
  someArr.forEach((elem, index) => {

    let type = typeof elem;

    if (type.charAt(0) === "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u") {
      let n = "n"
    } else {
      let n = ""
    }

    console.log(`element ${elem} at index number: ${index} is a${n} ${type}`)
  })
}

///////////

arrayTypeFinder(someArr) //=> n is not defined
```

Comment: N isn't defined globally its defined locally to the `if` and `else` statements

Comment: Another issue with your code is that you need to check if the first character is "a", OR (||)  the first character is "e", etc... so you need to chang your condition to be `type.charAt(0) === "a" || type.charAt(0) === "e" || ...`

Comment: `if ("aeiou".includes(type.charAt(0)) { // add n }`

Answer (score 2):

u need to define outside if condition

```
let n = ""
if (type.charAt(0) === "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u") {
    n = "n"
}
```

or you can use like this

```
let n= (type.charAt(0) === "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u") ? "n" :"";
```

Comment: `type.charAt(0) === "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u"` is not the correct way to check if `type.charAt(0)` equals an vowel, `n` it will always be set to `"n"`

Answer (score 0):

One option is using `var` instead of `let`.

This way, `n` is *declared* in all the relevant scope. Having `undefined` value before assignment:

```js
    console.log(n) // undefined, not "ReferenceError: n is not defined", even before any assignment
    if (type.charAt(0) === "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u") {
      var n = "n"
    } else {
      var n = ""
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it works using a combination of your answers! thanks!

```
function arrayTypeFinder(array) {
  someArr.forEach((elem, index) => {

    let type = typeof elem;

    let n = (type.charAt(0) === "a" || type.charAt(0) === "e" || type.charAt(0) === "i" || type.charAt(0) === "o" || type.charAt(0) === "u") ? "n" : "";

    console.log(`element ${elem} at index number: ${index} is a${n} ${type}`)
  })
}
```